# how to input nodejs variable into oracle sql query

Tags: sql, node.js

I am trying to pass a nodejs variable to a sql query
Below is my code:

```
var b= 101;
connection = await oracledb.getConnection(  {
user          : dbConfig.user,
password      : dbConfig.password,
connectString : dbConfig.connectString
});
sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytab where id= b';
binds = {};
                        options = {
                        outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT   // query result format
                        };

                        result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
```

Comment: Not very familiar with nodejs, but I'm guessing `binds = {"b": 123};` and `sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytab where id=:b';`. Notice the colon char.

Comment: Thanks! it worked.

Comment: There are plenty of [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) and even [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html) to learn from

Answer (score 0):

try something along these lines:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM mytab where id= $1::int';
options = {
    outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT   // query result format
};

result = await connection.execute(sql, [ b ], options);
```